# How to check that an order is payed in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I need to display information this is a new customer or returning customer in order details. To do this, I check if the customer with the current id has completed orders, if there are more than 2, then he is a returning customer. I also need to display information about the number of completed orders by a current customer. And for an administrator, everything is displayed correctly, but if I look under the role of a shop manager, then I see incorrect information. It seems to me that it is necessary to add another check for the time of payment and if the time is NULL, then this order has not yet been completed.
This is my code, help me please add a check for the time of payment

```php
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'renderCustomerIsNewField' );

 function renderCustomerIsNewField($order){
    $customer_has_existing_orders  = wc_get_orders(
        array(
            'customer_id' => $order->get_user_id(),
            'status' => 'completed'
        )
    );

    $orders_count = count($customer_has_existing_orders);

    $markData = ( (int)count($customer_has_existing_orders) >= 2)
        ? array('status-processing', 'Returning customer')
        : array('status-on-hold', 'New Customer');
    
    echo '
    <p>
        <mark class="order-status '. $markData[0] .'">
            <span>'. $markData[1] .' <strong style="color:#ff0000;font-weight: 900;"> '. $orders_count .'</strong></span>
        </mark>
    </p>
    ';
}
```

Comment: Some feed back on the answer below will be really appreciated please.

Answer (score 1):

**To check if an order is paid**, or to get the payment date time, you can use the [`WC_Order` method `get_date_paid()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/includes/class-wc-order.php). This method can return the `WC_DateTime` Object if the order is paid, otherwise it return a `null` value.

So in your code you can include something like:

```php
if( $order->get_date_paid() ) {
    // Order is paid - Do something
} else {
    // Order is NOT paid - Do something else
}
```